# How can I compute the probability distribution by using channel through Choi matrix in quantum process tomography?

Tags: quantum-process-tomography

The probability of observing an outcome corresponding to $M_j$ (a positive measurement operator), when the quantum process has transformed some input state $\rho_j$ is

$p_{ij}=tr[\mathcal{E}(\rho_i)M_j]$.

The evolution of a generic quantum state ρ under the channel E is obtained through the Choi matrix as $\mathcal{E}(\rho)=tr_{\sigma}[(\rho^T\otimes I_{\tau})\Lambda]$, where $\Lambda$ is the Choi matrix.

How can I get $p_{ij}$ by substituting $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$, cause there is already a partical trace in $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$, which will be $p_{ij}=tr\{tr_{\sigma}[(\rho^T\otimes I_{\tau})\Lambda]M_j\}$, seems terrible.

Answer (score 1):

The Choi is related to the channel via
$$\Lambda = \sum_{ij} (E_{ij}\otimes \mathcal E(E_{ij}))
= (I\otimes \mathcal E)\mathbb{P}_+,$$
using the shorthand notation $E_{ij}\equiv |i\rangle\!\langle j|$ and $\mathbb{P}_+\equiv |+\rangle\!\langle +|$, $|+\rangle\equiv \sum_i|i,i\rangle$.

As you already pointed out, you recover the channel $\mathcal E$ from $\Lambda$ via
$$\mathcal E(\rho) = \operatorname{tr}_1[(\rho^T\otimes I)\Lambda].$$
Using these to compute probabilities you get
$$\operatorname{tr}(M\mathcal E(\rho))
= \operatorname{tr}[M\operatorname{tr}_1[(\rho^T\otimes I)\Lambda]]
= \operatorname{tr}[(\rho^T\otimes M) \Lambda].$$
Intuitively, you see this because the second space of $\Lambda$ is not affected by multiplication by $\rho^T$ nor by the partial trace, therefore the outer multiplication by $M$ directly connected to $\Lambda$.

More formally, you can show this expanding the partial trace explicitly:
$$\operatorname{tr}_1[(\rho^T\otimes I)\Lambda]
= \sum_i (\langle i|\otimes I) [(\rho^T\otimes I)\Lambda](|i\rangle\otimes I)
= \sum_{ijk\ell} \rho_{ji} \Lambda_{jk,i\ell} E_{k\ell},$$
and thus
$$\operatorname{tr}(M\mathcal E(\rho))
= \sum_{\alpha\beta} \bar M_{\alpha\beta} \mathcal E(\rho)_{\alpha\beta}
= \sum_{ij\alpha\beta} \bar M_{\alpha\beta} \rho_{ji} \Lambda_{j\alpha,i\beta}
= \operatorname{tr}[(\rho^T\otimes M)\Lambda].$$